# Unhandled exception at 0x013f3277 in bloom_filter_prl.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow

Tags: c++, exception, stack-overflow

i get the above error when i try to debug my program in vc 2010. it happens at the first line of the main function where I have the following line

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    std::vector<std::string> word_list;
```

when i break the debugging it goes to "chkstk.stm" and indicates the possible error to be the following==>

> Find next lower page and probe cs20:
>
> ```
>     sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
>     test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.
>     jmp     short cs10
> ```
>
> _chkstk endp
>
> ```
>     end
> ```

Comment: Unless you're doing massive allocations on the lines before that (unlikely), this line won't cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: the line before this line is: int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

Comment: Tom means that we need to see more of the program source! Anyway, I'll give you +1 for stackoverflow. Especially when you get it allocating a zero-length array. But tell me, do other programs compiled with the same compiler run normally?

Comment: @MrLister: the source code is very big and I am not sure which part is making this error and so which part to post here

Comment: Based on this code, I would be looking at any static objects' constructors, since they will all be getting called as the program starts.  Your problem is not in the code you posted, but in code that runs prior to this.

Comment: @MrLister: yes it compiles and runs well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to have large allocations on one of my user defined header files.